# Are champion and skin sales on a fixed rotation?

Tags: league-of-legends

I only buy champions and skins when they go on sale. Is there a way to know what will go on sale ahead of time, or is it completely random?

Answer (score 3):

No, they usually do a poll and ask the community what skins they would like to see on sale to benefit them and to profit and pocket the most money. A brilliant strategy, in my opinion.

As for champions, anytime they release a new champ, it will be free 2 weeks later in that rotation. That's the only thing that's set in stone with the champion rotation, otherwise they balance out bruisers, AP and AD carries, jungle and supports.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the poll?

Answer (score 0):

I usually find that skins are on sale within a month of releasing or on the holidays. New champions usually become free 2 weeks after they come out. This doesn't always happen but I'm just trying to help. =D

Answer (score -2):

No, they generally put things on sale that aren't selling too well so they get the money.