# Is there any schedule for sales on champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing with Ahri for the past few days (she is on the free-to-play rotation this week), and I really like the way she plays. Currently, she costs 6300IP which may not seem like a lot to players who've been playing for a long time and have accumulated a great deal of IP, but in my case that is a lot. I'm just below seven-thousand IP, but I just want to know if there is a schedule of any kind for sales.

In short: is there any way for me to tell if Ahri (or other champions) will go on sale? or am I better off just buying her instead of holding my breath?

I know that older champions get cheaper over time, but I'm not sure when Ahri was released. Also I looked at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59002/are-champion-and-skin-sales-on-a-fixed-rotation), but I feel as though it doesn't address what I'm looking for.

**Note: I'm only spending with IP not RP.**

Comment: I believe Ahri's got another 6-7 champs in front of her to have their price reduced. Which would end up being late this year (assuming one champ release per month) or early next.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Huh, ok. Well I guess it is matter of when I want it. I really would like to player her more, but she won't be going anywhere so I can always buy her later on.

Comment: Not trying to be a naysayer or anything. But from personal experience, price changes rarely happen to champions that are still considered powerful even after they have been out for a while. I would say it has more to do with the percentage of the player base that plays any specific champion on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sales are always announced the day before it starts. So other than that there is no warning.

Here is a [list of previous sales](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=28808024). Searching for Ahri you can see she was somewhat recently on sale (April 5-8) which means she probably won't be again for a while.

This [google docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApNQRbuc_G9gdG8wQWxiV0xoT0RlTW44MU1RSEV2YUE#gid=0) is completely fan-made and theoretical, but predicts what future sales could be based on how long it's been since a champion has last been for sale. Can be a bit useful but remember, it's not official at all.

Comment: Well as you said since she recently had a sale it'll be a bit. I think I'll end up biting the bullet and buying her. So far I really love the way she plays.

Comment: @Scootaloo Yea might as well. Besides, why use RP for something you can just get with free IP? :D

Comment: I actually was talking about IP only, I'll edit the OP.

Comment: That's my bad, I just assumed you meant RP when you said sale. (Since there's no such thing as an IP sale)

Comment: Well what I meant was when will the IP price be reduced. I know after a certain amount of time the price will go down in IP. For Ahri I doubt it'll happen any time soon seeing as she is not that old.

Comment: In that case you might want to look at [this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/champion-pricing-timing-changes) and [this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/champion-price-reduction). First is how they decided to do price changes and second is the most recent schdeuled price changes.

Comment: Aatrox is champ 5 for this year meaning Riven is the next to be lowered. After Riven we won't know who's next until Riot posts which shouldn't be too long after.

Comment: Ya. A tiny part of me wants to get Aatrox, but I know that'd be a huge waste of IP and my time.

Answer (score 2):

When there are sales, only the RP price reduces and not the IP price.

Answer (score 1):

The current Riot IP pricing policy is, that the latest release is 7800 IP for a week before dropping to 6300 IP. Concurrently with the release of a new champion, the oldest one at 6300 IP gets reduced to 4800 IP.

As an example, with the Vel'Koz release they have reduced the cost of Shyvana to 4800 IP. You can sort the [list of champions](http://www.lolking.net/champions/) on LoLKing by release date to see which is the oldest champion who is next in line for a reduction.

Re. Ahri, she is 3rd in line after Fizz and Volibear. Lately champion releases have been more infrequent, if we assume that it takes 2 months on average between new champions then she should be free in another 6 months (from Vel'Koz release). Of course, this is highly variable depending on what Riot has in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

When 3 or 4 new champs get released, the 3 oldest  6300 champs get their price reduced I think. So when Lucian becomes avaliable , talon, skarner and someone else willbe reduced to 4800IP. As for Ahri, you'll be waiting for a while.